# Body is not define in Python REST

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I am using python  `requests`   to make a POST REST request .

Here is code

```
REST_URLU = REST_URL+'user/'+get_usermain.username
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8','Accept':'application/json; charset=UTF-8','X-Talisman-Secret':API_KEY}
payload = {"org_name":ORG_KEY,
          "first_name":full.first_name.encode('utf8'),
         "middle_name" : "ranjan",
         "last_name" : "dubey",    
         "passwd":"9454545", 
         "city" : "Gwalior",
         "state" : "Madhya Pradesh",
         "country" : "India",
         "pin" : "560068",
         "street" : "Cocx town",
         "primary_landline" : "080255555",
         "primary_mobile":"584644884",
         "primary_phon" : "0558877822558",
         "primary_email":get_usermain.email.encode('utf8'),
         }

print payload
print "resttttttttttttttttt"
print REST_URLU

print "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
r = requests.post(REST_URLU, params=payload,headers = headers)
```

Now the problem is whenever i am posting the same body like

```
{"org_name":"45668",
              "first_name":"NAME",
             "middle_name" : "ranjan",
             "last_name" : "dubey",    
             "passwd":"9454545", 
             "city" : "Gwalior",
             "state" : "Madhya Pradesh",
             "country" : "India",
             "pin" : "560068",
             "street" : "Cocx town",
             "primary_landline" : "080255555",
             "primary_mobile":"584644884",
             "primary_phon" : "0558877822558",
             "primary_email":"someemail@hi.com",
             }
```

From Mozilla REST client 
It is working fine .But the same Body when I am using in Python it is not working .

lease help me What might I am doing wrong .

Answer (score 3):

My bet is that you need to pass your content as `data=json.dumps(payload)` to `requests.post()` instead of as `params`.  Docs say that `params` become url parameters, whereas you want this as a JSON-encoded message body.